# how to apply a function to each row in a pandas date frame to generate a new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with a date index and a function (prevRate, below) to work out if a value has increased or decreased from the previous day.

```
def prevRate(currentDate, df):
  prevDate = currentDate.date() - timedelta(days=1)
  prevRate =df.loc[prevDate,'Total per Million'].item()
  currentRate = df.loc[currentDate.date(),'Total  per Million'].item()



  if prevRate>currentRate:
    rateChange='inc'
  else:
    rateChange='dec'
  return rateChange
```

The data frame has the date as an index, and I want to apply the prevRate function to each of the index values to create a new field with each value as either 'inc' or 'dec'.

I am tried applying the function as below

```
df['rateChange']=df.apply(prevRate(df.index.get_level_values(0).item().to_pydatetime(),df))
```

and just using the function as in

```
df['rateChange']=prevRate(df.index.item().to_pydatetime(),df)
```

These approaches seem to extract the whole index rather then one item at a time.

current error message is

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-0d45be10dffa> in <module>
----> 1 df['rateChange']=df.apply(prevRate(df.index.item().to_pydatetime(),df))


  

      329         if len(self) == 1:
        330             return next(iter(self))
    --> 331         raise ValueError("can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar")
        332 
        333     @property
    
    ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Any suggestions as to how to apply the function to each row and generate a new column?

Comment: Are you perhaps just missing an ```.apply(..., axis=1)``` to apply to each row?

Comment: I thought you might be right, but nope, still getting the same error (now added to the question!)

Comment: Is it daily data ? Maybe you don't need to calc the prevDate if you just compare each row to the previous one

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you just need to compare each row with the previous one. One way to do is with `np.where`.

Since you didn't provide some sample data, here is the Input I used for demonstration:

```
np.random.seed(20)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date' : pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-01-10'),
    'num' : np.random.randint(0, 100, size=10)
})
print(df)

        Date  num
0 2022-01-01   99
1 2022-01-02   90
2 2022-01-03   15
3 2022-01-04   95
4 2022-01-05   28
5 2022-01-06   90
6 2022-01-07    9
7 2022-01-08   20
8 2022-01-09   75
9 2022-01-10   22
```

```
df['rateChange'] = np.where(df.num > df.num.shift(), 'inc', 'dec')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        Date  num rateChange
0 2022-01-01   99        dec
1 2022-01-02   90        dec
2 2022-01-03   15        dec
3 2022-01-04   95        inc
4 2022-01-05   28        dec
5 2022-01-06   90        inc
6 2022-01-07    9        dec
7 2022-01-08   20        inc
8 2022-01-09   75        inc
9 2022-01-10   22        dec
```